# Ng-model not reacting to change in chained ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am seeing some odd behavior when chaining select elements with ng-options built off of an array of objects. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4638/)

The scope property "filter.option" does not get reset when changing the scope property "filter.general", but the drop-down does.

Mandatory code of the array:

```
$scope.filterData = [
{"name" : "Users", "options" : []},
{"name" : "Data calls", "options" : [{"title": "Collection"}, {"title": "User"}]},
{"name" : "Msg Pub", "options" : [{"title": "Topic"}, {"title": "User"}]},
{"name" : "Msg Sub", "options" : [{"title": "Topic"}, {"title": "User"}]}
];
```

I came up with a hack using ng-change that wipes "filter.option" to get the desired behavior. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4639/)

Does anyone know why this is happening? It seems to be because the "filter.option" model is not bound to the "filter.general" model and therefore does not reflect any changes to the latter. Is there a way to build the second model off of the first one? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, there is nothing in changing the 'filter.general' which is telling 'filter.option' to update.

Hopefully somebody else can say why, I seem to recall something about angular.js not liking to update values to null, but also, sometimes values just don't update like you hoped. Sorry I can't provide more info on the matter.

However, a solution, I have. 
Here's a jsfiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4643/

You need to do two things. 
First, use
`ng-change` on your general field to tell angular when that field changes.

Then in your controller, have a 'reset' method which points to the first option in the select dropdown (the empty select). 
`return $scope.filter.option = $scope.filter.option[0];`

I know it seems weird, but I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems we came up with similar solutions. I am going to keep this question unanswered in hopes that someone will know why this is happening and possibly provide a "correct" method. I will accept your answer in a few days if no one can come up with a "proper" approach.